# Spring Boot Authorization server (SSO Implementation)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I am Having 3 Application for this I am building 1 authorization server  for better communication and security.
and also i want to do SSO on this 3 application where my authorization server will act as a Identity provider.

my question is how can i inter-communicate with this 3 application means.

1. for A Service I authenticate the user and get access token then i want to communicate with B -service then how can i do this with access token ?
2. and one more scenario if someone logins into my B-service then i want to give access for other 2 services(A and C) ?
3. Implementing SSO with Authorization server is it possible ?
   note- I dont want 3rd party implementation (Keyclock, okta) want to build or own

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you will have `auth-server` for all these 3 apps. From Service to Service communication that is usually an [resource-server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) you will pass token in request headers and that`s all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AndreiLisa
Yes  that is used to communicate service to service. 
What about SSO Implementation ?

Comment: spring boot, from 3.1.x also provide an starter for [authorization-server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/index.html). Where you can create your own  SSO with Authorization